# has no address records (A or AAAA) not loaded due to errors

Tags: dns

tengo problemas con mi DNS al momento de verificar, mis configuraciones son las siguientes:

```
 zone "sisecc.ddns.net"{
type master;
file "db.sisec.zone";
notify yes;
};

//Zona inversa
zone "118.240.148.in-addr.arpa"{
type master;
file "db.148.240.118";
notify yes;
};
```

mi zona directa es la siguiente:

```
   ;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
 @  IN  SOA sisecc.ddns.net. root.sisecc.ddns.net. (
              2     ; Serial
         604800     ; Refresh
          86400     ; Retry
        2419200     ; Expire
         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
 ;
 @          IN  NS  sisecc.ddns.net.
  sisecc.ddns.net       IN  A   148.240.118.40
  www.sisecc.ddns.net   IN      A       148.240.118.40
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el mensaje de error completo en la pregunta con algunas líneas más de contexto? Por lo pronto he encontrado un error en tu archivo de zona, pero es probable que haya alguno más.